# Replace SimpleAdapter in android development to improve code quality

Tags: java, android, arraylist

At the moment, I use a `HashMap<String, String>` and a `SimpleAdapter` object to display user data in my `ListView`, but now I want to replace the `HashMap<String, String>` with an `ArrayList<User>();` containing real user objects.

Here is my code:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put(TAG_USERNAME, c.getString(TAG_USERNAME));
                map.put(TAG_FIRSTNAME, c.getString(TAG_FIRSTNAME));
                map.put(TAG_LASTNAME, c.getString(TAG_LASTNAME));
                map.put(TAG_ADDRESS, c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS));
                usersList.add(map);
```

[...]

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, usersList,
                    R.layout.single_user, new String[] { TAG_USERNAME,
                            TAG_FIRSTNAME, TAG_LASTNAME, TAG_ADDRESS },
                    new int[] { R.id.textViewUsername, R.id.textViewFirstName,
                            R.id.textViewLastName, R.id.textViewAddress });
```

How is it possible to replace the `HashMap` with the `ArrayList`? Is there a specific class for this purpose?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way would be to override `toString` inside your User class in order to return the information you want to display, and use an `ArrayAdapter<User>`. Or you can have your `CustomAdapter`, which extends `BaseAdapter` and implements its abstract method. In particulare you have the `getCount` method, which returns the number of elements that your dataset holds, `getItem(int position)` which returns the object of your dataset at position, and `getView(int, View, ViewGroup)`, that you have to use to inflate and customize your view

Comment: Thank you for your help. When using `ArrayAdapter<User>`, I need to loop over my `ArrayList<User>` and always call `user.toString()` in order to get an Array of all user information, right?

Comment: No, the adapter will take care of it

Comment: Ok, but when I call it like this `ListAdapter arrAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<User>(this, R.layout.single_user, usersArrList);` I get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView`, because I have multiple TextViews and I was not able to apply multiple id's as parameters like in `SimpleAdapter`.

Comment: Then you have to subclass it. You could also subclass ArrayAdaper<User> and override only the getview